# Retrieve a list of elements using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm pretty new with hibernate so I hope that you guys can help me.

I have a 2 tables, one to many relationship

[image: Usiarios has many feedbacks]

Using Hibernate reverse engineering I created the entities (lets focus in the fields)

[image: JPA annotation referencing one to many relationship]

I'm trying to get a User and then get the related feedbacks using the
"get" method. But this returns me an empty list.

[image: feedbacks is an empty list]

What I'm doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

This is the code of "getUserMethod", notice that I'm extending CrudRepository.

[image: userService implementation is using "userRepository"]

**UPDATE 2**

I'm using SecurityContextHolder as Ismael sugest but it seems that 
my Principal object is empty. With Principal I'm only getting the 
user name, so I'm searching on DB and retrieving that user, the problem persist. =(

[image]

Comment: please share code correlated to userService.getUser(auth.getName());

Comment: thanks! I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get authenticated user, you need to use the following instead:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

This is not a copy/paste solution, so please try to use that according to your application context and such.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Context to get the username from Principal object and then look for it on DB. The problem persist, check my update.

Comment: Try to upload your application into github and I will replicate the process on my end to see what is missing...